# How to test a legacy application (and adopt Test Driven Development) without introducing risk?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, tdd

I have been asked to bring an old java based application up to date and inline with more current apps I have worked on.

One of the things we would like to introduce is Test driven Dev for any new enhancements.

The code unit test coverage is currently very low <20%

As someone new to the application I would like this percentage to be a lot larger to give me the confidence to make changes without introducing defects.

Problem is to get this percentage up, a lot of the code would require re-factoring to be testable.

So Re-factoring with such low unit test coverage could introduce issues, but to get the test coverage up you have to re-factor?!

Is there anyway to lower the risk when trying to do this??

Comment: Out of interest, how are you calculating your coverage? Private methods should be tested indirectly by methods with a wider scope (public/protected) - they don't require their own tests...

Comment: Yes I agree . Coverage statistics are coming out of Sonar. I have also used EclEmma plugin for eclipse. Thanks

Comment: So are you refactoring purely to increase the coverage or is this a separate activity (to bring it into line with the current apps)?

Comment: Purely for test coverage

Comment: I've never used the particular product you describe but you don't normally have to change the code to add unit tests. They normally sit inside a separate library.

Comment: I think your missing the point to be honest. The 'product' is an internal application so you would never use it?? Point is, code can be written in a way that is difficult to test. Code not unit tested when written often results in untestable code. An example (mentioned in answer below) are classes which create other dependencies internally. To test these classes you must also set-up there dependencies. Hence the use of IOC, provides cleaner code and code which is easier to test (as mocks of the dependencies can be passed in instead of the real implementation).

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I'd never used Sonar. I can see why you'd want to refactor if you've got DI/mocking frameworks going on but retrofitting TDD to an existing development is kind of against the general ethos - the tail wagging the dog if you will.

Comment: Surely improving test coverage is a worthwhile goal in and of itself?  And using TDD for new enhancements make sense - its certainly how I try to work (but again, the state of the existing code may or may not lend itself to TDD initially). Additionally, improving code coverage improves understanding of the app, which in turn means that breaking something when adding a new enhancement is far less likely than if they hadn/t refactored/added tests.

Comment: There are many facets to TDD of which automated testing is but one. TDD is really about driving design and development via testing. You can't do this in reverse by the very nature of it. This is turning into a longer thread than I wanted it to be so cutting to the chase: there is limited value in trying to retrofit each new technology into every legacy application. Introducing mocking frameworks and DI into even a small application is a considerable amount of work. I'm not knocking the idea per se (it will lead to better code) but it is a difficult sell as the benefits are often intangible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The low risk approach to this is to test & refactor is very small increments.  You have to introduce as many tests that you can before modifying anything (not always easy), and then continue the process but including refactorin into the mix.

If you keep your initial refactoring to extracting self contained blocks of code into small self contained methods then the risk is low (not risk free, but low) and you can then test both the original method as best you can, but additionally test the extracted method thoroughly.

Mocking also helps a great deal with this - you're able to pass in mocks instead of real services etc which assists a great deal. You're still left with troublesome scenarios where the code is instantiating/calling a service internally that you dont want to test, but over time you can also work around this by introducing dependency injection (so that you can inject mocks instead of real services).  But this is probably a longer term strategy.

The way I've done this in the past is to be pragmatic about it - initially is seems insurmountable, but if you do the above often and repeatedly in time you do end up with code you're no longer "scared" of.  It takes time, but it can be done.

I can thoroughly recommend [Michael Feather's Working with Legacy Code](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Robert-Martin/dp/0131177052) for this sort of thing - its offers many practical strategies in dealing with the very problem you (and we all experience, at some point) are facing

Comment: Yep - not a very sexy topic but it is one most of us have to deal with at some point...